# Refresh form submission not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

After googling the web, I could not find the correct solution to my code.  Here  I am linking the JQuery with ajax google libraries for HTML FORM validation.  It works fine but not refreshing after form successful form submission. Please guide me.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function Submit(){
    var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
    var formemail = $("#femail").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
        var name = $("#place").val();
    var femail = $("#femail").val();

        if($("#name").val() == "" ){
            $("#name").focus();
            $("#error").html("Enter the Name.");
            return false;
        }else if($("#place").val() == "" ){
                $("#place").focus();
                $("#error").html("Enter the Place.");
                return false;
        }else if($("#femail").val() == "" ){
                $("#femail").focus();
                $("#error").html("Enter the email.");
                return false;
        }else if(!emailRegex.test(formemail)){
                $("#femail").focus();
                $("#error").html("Enter the valid email.");
                return false;
        }else if($(name != '' && place != '' && femail != '')){
            $("#error").html("Form submitted successfully.")
                }
         }
</script>

<form id="form_name" name="form" method="post" action="   ">
   <div id="error"></div>
       NAME:  <input type="text" name="Name"  id="name" > <br>
       PLACE:  <input type="text" name="Place" id="place"> <br>
       EMAIL:  <input type="text" name="Email" id="femail"> <br><br> 
       <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="Submit()"/>
</form>
```

Once the HTML form is submitted, it is showing "Form submitted successfully" then the form to be refreshed.

Comment: `type="button"` will not submit the form...

Comment: On your last `elseif`reset the inputs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the changes suggested by Rayon, you could refresh you form by placing `$("#form_name")[0].reset()` right below  `$("#error").html("Form submitted successfully.")`:

```
function Submit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // You will have to submit your form using ajax.
    var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
    var formemail = $("#femail").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
        var name = $("#place").val();
    var femail = $("#femail").val();

        if($("#name").val() == "" ){
            $("#name").focus();
            $("#error").html("Enter the Name.");
            return false;
        }else if($("#place").val() == "" ){
                $("#place").focus();
                $("#error").html("Enter the Place.");
                return false;
        }else if($("#femail").val() == "" ){
                $("#femail").focus();
                $("#error").html("Enter the email.");
                return false;
        }else if(!emailRegex.test(formemail)){
                $("#femail").focus();
                $("#error").html("Enter the valid email.");
                return false;
        }else if($(name != '' && place != '' && femail != '')){
            $("#error").html("Form submitted successfully.")
            $("#form_name")[0].reset();
         }
     }
```

But if you are not submitting your form using ajax your page is going to get reloaded which defeats the purpose of displaying a "form submitted successfully" message.

Comment: I have checked, after entering data in first filed, it is giving success and auto refreshing.

Comment: @guruje did you modify your input to pass an event? <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="Submit(e)"/>? it works fine for me. If I enter only one field it asks for the remaining fields

Answer (score 1):

> Having `type = 'button'`, it will not act as `submit-button`

- Use `type = "submit"`
- Use `event.preventdefault()` to prevent form submission if client-side-validation fails

```js
function Submit(e) {
  var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
  var formemail = $("#femail").val();
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var name = $("#place").val();
  var femail = $("#femail").val();

  if ($("#name").val() == "") {
    $("#name").focus();
    $("#error").html("Enter the Name.");
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if ($("#place").val() == "") {
    $("#place").focus();
    $("#error").html("Enter the Place.");
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if ($("#femail").val() == "") {
    $("#femail").focus();
    $("#error").html("Enter the email.");
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (!emailRegex.test(formemail)) {
    $("#femail").focus();
    $("#error").html("Enter the valid email.");
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if ($(name != '' && place != '' && femail != '')) {
    $("#error").html("Form submitted successfully.")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form_name" name="form" method="post" action="   ">
  <div id="error"></div>
  NAME:
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="name">
  <br>PLACE:
  <input type="text" name="Place" id="place">
  <br>EMAIL:
  <input type="text" name="Email" id="femail">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="Submit(event)" />
</form>
```

Comment: Working fine as earlier, but the refresh is not materialized.

Comment: @guruje, In SO snippets, form submission is prevented..test in your code..

Comment: @guruje — Are you using `ajax` form submit ?

Comment: Sir, I checked,   it is shwoing success and refresh, with entering first filed

Comment: @guruje — I am unable to understand you.. In simple terms, Is it working ?

Comment: I am not using AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Use below function...

```
location.reload(true);

window.location.reload()

window.location.href=window.location.href
```

Comment: Once the success message is appeared, then only the refresh to be happened.

Answer (score 0):

**Two steps you should do in your program as follows**

1. Need to give name of form use the below one

< form id="form_name" name="form" method="post" action="   ">

instead of above line u

**< form name="form" id="form_name" name="form" method="post" action="   " >**

2.add the line in your script "Submit"

**document.form.reset();**

//Here **"form"** is name of your form